# Trying to Decomp minecraft forge workspace, this happens when I try to do that

Tags: minecraft

To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.14/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Unable to start the daemon process.
  This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
  For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
  Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.14/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

  ### Please read the following process output to find out more:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 3145728KB object heap

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: What is your question? We need more details. How you're "decomp", what system you're using, etc. Please edit your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, but I found out it may be because you downloaded the jdk for a 32 bit windows while you have a 64 bit Windows / viceversa.